# Multiple location XSLT for each select

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, svg

I have been busting a nut last few days trying to solve a code issue of getting java script to display XML in a table from an SVG. I did ask here but got no reply and I understand why as it was a lot easier than I thought it would be.

I have solved that but am stuck once again, although I have one state displaying the correct details, I need to do it for the rest of the states, I want to know if I will need and XSLT for each one or if I can do it all on the same xslt?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Map of vaults by state </title>


<script>
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else 
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function California()
{
xml = loadXMLDoc("vaults.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("map.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("vaulttable").innerHTML = ex;
  }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById("vaulttable").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>


<svg id="svg3508" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="159.41mm" width="255.48mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 905.24105 564.82529" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <g id="layer1" transform="translate(58.335 -367.09)">

  <path id="NV" class="state nv" d="m116.26 545.06-23.639 128.82-1.8322 0.34915-1.5728 2.4062-2.3729 0.0107-1.472-2.7435-2.6185-0.37842-0.77092-1.1076-1.0378-0.054-2.7784 1.6443-0.31026 6.7855-0.36209 5.7772-0.34857 8.5928-1.4471 2.0892-2.4389-1.074l-69.083-104.21 18.989-67.59 93.092 20.666z"/>



 <a xlink:href="javascript:California()">
  <path id="CA" class="state ca" d="m64.558 741.68 3.9401-0.48862 1.486-2.0114 0.54454-2.9411-3.5515-0.59012-0.51417-0.66822 0.4775-2.0323-0.15928-0.58967 1.9226-0.61959 3.0428-2.8327 0.58156-4.9951 1.3799-3.4021 1.9433-2.1663 3.5189-1.5897 1.6544-1.6048 0.0687-2.1088-0.99333-0.58001-1.0232-1.0727-1.1552-5.8484-2.6852-4.8301 0.56581-3.505-2.4196-1.0293-69.061-104.18 18.902-67.601-67.08-15.698-1.5069 4.7332-0.16166 7.4364-5.1731 11.801-3.0715 2.5866-0.32332 1.1316-1.7783 0.80831-1.4549 4.2032-0.8083 3.2332 2.7482 4.2032 1.6166 4.2032 1.1316 3.5565-0.32332 6.4664-1.7783 3.0716-0.64664 5.8198-0.96996 3.7182 1.7783 3.8798 2.7482 4.5265 2.2632 4.8498 1.2933 4.0415-0.32332 3.2332-0.32332 0.48498v2.1016l5.6581 6.3048-0.48498 2.4249-0.64664 2.2632-0.64664 1.9399 0.16166 8.2447 2.1016 3.7182 1.9399 2.5866 2.7482 0.48499 0.96996 2.7482-1.1316 3.5565-2.1016 1.6166h-1.1316l-0.8083 3.8798 0.48498 2.9099 3.2332 4.3648 1.6166 5.3348 1.4549 4.6882 1.2933 3.0716 3.3949 5.8198 1.4549 2.5866 0.48498 2.9099 1.6166 0.96996v2.4249l-0.8083 1.9399-1.7783 7.1131-0.48498 1.9399 2.4249 2.7482 4.2032 0.48498 4.5265 1.7783 3.8799 2.1016h2.9099l2.9099 3.0716 2.5866 4.8498 1.1316 2.2632 3.8799 2.1016 4.8498 0.8083 1.4549 2.1016 0.64664 3.2332-1.4549 0.64664 0.32332 0.96996 3.2332 0.8083 2.7482 0.16167 3.1599-1.6868 3.8799 4.2032 0.8083 2.2632 2.5866 4.2032 0.32332 3.2332v9.3763l0.48498 1.7783 10.023 1.455 19.723 2.7482 13.845 1.3497zm-88.135-43.717 1.2933 1.5358-0.16166 1.2933-3.2332-0.0808-0.56581-1.2125-0.64664-1.455 3.3141-0.0808zm1.9399 0 1.2125-0.64664 3.5565 2.1016 3.0716 1.2124-0.88914 0.64666-4.5265-0.2425-1.6166-1.6166-0.80831-1.455zm20.693 19.803 1.7783 2.3441 0.80831 0.96997 1.5358 0.56581 0.56581-1.455-0.96996-1.7783-2.6674-2.0208-1.0508 0.16166v1.2125zm-1.455 8.6489 1.7783 3.1524 1.2125 1.9399-1.455 0.24248-1.2933-1.2124s-0.72748-1.455-0.72748-1.8591v-2.1824l0.48498-0.0808z"/>
    </a>     
 </g>
</svg>

</body>
<div id="vaulttable" />
</body>
</html>
```

So that is the main html page, at the moment it has CA and NV, the XSLT I currently have does a XSL value of select on the state in the XML file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Vault found in state</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">vaultname</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="vaults/vault[state='California']">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="vaultname" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the XML I have here is a cut down version of just a single vault from each of the two states, so if you click on California it displays the LA vault, now I would like it so I only need the single XSL file for each state. At the moment I can do it if I copy the function from the map.html page and rename the function for each state and have separate XSL files but there must be a cleaner way of doing it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<vaults xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vaults.xsd">
  <vault>
    <vaultname>Los Angeles Vault </vaultname>
    <state>California</state>
    <location>Los Angeles (Cathedral)</location>
    <description>The Vault-Tec demonstration vault. It was not part of the experiment, and was the Master's vault under the Cathedral. </description>
    <fate> </fate>
    <appearance>Fallout</appearance>
  </vault>
  <vault>
    <vaultname>Vault 3</vaultname>
    <state>Nevada</state>
    <location>West of Las Vegas</location>
    <description>A control vault designed to open after 20 years, but kept closed longer due to the wishes of the vault inhabitants.</description>
    <fate> unplanned water leak forced the occupants to open in hopes of trading with the outside. Unfortunately, all of the vault's residents were massacred by a group of raiders known as the Fiends shortly after they opened the vault door.</fate>
    <appearance>Fallout New Vegas</appearance>
  </vault>
</vaults>
```

So a person clicks on CA at the moment a table is show that displays the vault name in a div at the bottom of the page, I would like so if they select NV it will display the vault for NV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters to your xslt-stylesheet like this:

```
xsltProcessor.setParameter(null,"state","California");
```

and then in your XSLT you can do

```
<xsl:for-each select="vaults/vault[state=$state]">
```

for more details, and crossbrowser compat, see the answer to this question:
[How to pass parameter to XSLT from Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124455/how-to-pass-parameter-to-xslt-from-javascript-function)